# print specific request header python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, python-requests

I am attempting to extract a specific request header using python, the 'plib' to be exact after logging into my account to automate the login. I have successful logged in and printed out all the request headers using seleniumwire but i need one saved to a variable.

```
for request in driver.requests:
  #print(request.url) # <--------------- Request url
  print(request.headers) # <----------- Request headers
  #print(request.response.headers) # <-- Response headers
```

that is what i am using to print all the request header but i just need one. Can someone please assist ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can index into the `headers` property like you would with a dictionary.

```
print(request.headers["plib"])
```

To quote from [the documentation](https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/#request-objects):

> `headers`
>
> A dictionary-like object of request headers. Headers are case-insensitive and duplicates are permitted. Asking for
> `request.headers['user-agent']` will return the value of the `User-Agent`
> header. If you wish to replace a header, make sure you delete the
> existing header first with `del request.headers['header-name']`,
> otherwise you’ll create a duplicate.

Comment: Hey Jack thank you so much :) when i print it though it prints none on every line but the plib, is there a way to get it to just print the plib once?

Comment: @Calllum That means that only one request you are making contains the `plib` header. If you don't know which request that is beforehand, you can check them all by using an `if` statement: `if request.headers["plib"]: print(request.headers["plib"])`.

Comment: hey Jack, i got it!! thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Calllum If that was helpful, please mark my answer as the accepted answer. :)